# How to tell which PHP files are actually used and which are not?

Tags: php, dependencies

I got a large PHP website which I'm now about to take care of. It contains hundreds of separate PHP files, but I suspect only less than a half is really being used. Most of them probably can be deleted.

But the last thing I really want to do is going through the code of each file and check whether its linked, included, required...etc. to others or whether it can be safely deleted.

Do you know whether there's any tool which is capable of doing this?

Comment: Good question, do keep in mind that you might not catch all files. Because you can include files dynamically and which files are included can depend on the state of variables.

Comment: Try this one also: http://php.net/inclued

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [**phpxref**](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/), It might do what you need.

> Cross-references PHP classes, functions, variables, constants and require/include usage.

Comment: That won't handle invocations via **eval**.  Nor will it handle groups of files that reference one another, but for which there is no reference from outside.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with analyzing the code with an automated tool is that you may find batches of files that link to each other, but the batch of files are never used.  Conversely, there may be a file that is accessed directly, but doesn't use other files, nor is it included by any other files.

Typically what I do, in desperation, is add logging to each file. Simple write `__FILE__` out to a log file when the file is accessed. This does add overhead across the board. But after a certain length of time, you then have your list of files are are actually accessed and used.

You could also analyze the log file on a regular basis and remove the logging from the files you know are used, reducing overhead as you go. In the end, you can search for files that still have your logging code to see which ones haven't been used.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [phpdcd](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpdcd)

> phpdcd is a Dead Code Detector (DCD) for PHP code. It scans a PHP project for all declared functions and methods and reports those as being "dead code" that are not called at least once.

But don't expect any wonders from it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but all will involve some manual work.

You can probably best install and use a debugger (like Xdebug) that can show you the path the PHP travels as you click through them.

Another way is to write a script that matches on 'include', 'include_once', 'require', 'require_once'. Possibly check for 'eval' and 'fopen', 'file_get_contents' etc too.
Make sure you test / backup.

Comment: And I just realized - any href=file.php is also a possible match !
So the script / grep approach should take that into consideration too.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a test coverage tool, it will tell which ones are definitely used,
for whatever functionality of the software you have exercised.  (Obviously, the more you exercise
the software, the more of it gets executed by the non-dead part.).  This includes any file accessible via an external html link; of course, you have to *exercise* that link, as it is part of your application functionality.

Then you can inspect the ones it says are not used do decide what the case really is.

Our [SD PHP Test Coverage tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PHPTestCoverage.html) will accept a list of *all* the files you wish to check out, and enable you to easily collect such test coverage data.  It provides a summary report showing which files have any coverage at all; those with 0% coverage are the ones that are likely dead.

Comment: Does it cover PHP scripts which are included? What about those which are called through an AJAX action?

I take it that to find dead code amongst a particular script, using a tool such as the one @Pekka or @gordon proposed would be more appropriate then.

Comment: @Eldros: It doesn't matter how the script gets invoked (include, via AJAX). The instrumentation placed in a file in the project list, will notice if the script is invoked, and will likewise notice the *absence* of invocation of the script.

Comment: @Eldros: So-called "static analysis" tools for determining the answer by inspecting just the source code are not likely to be accurate.  One can assemble a method name at runtime and use eval to call it; very few static analysis techniques (let alone the ones in the specific tools listed by others as answers) can determine this; so they may tell you something is not used even if it executes often; they may tell you something is used even if it never executes.  In contrast, the test coverage tool will always tell you correctly if something is *used* as evidenced by  execution.

Comment: This test coverage tool works on the scripts: It will only tell how often a script is called, but not particularly which part of the script was called, am I right?

Comment: @Eldros: It tells you precisely which parts of the scripts are executed, at the level of code blocks.  A summary report provides rollups which will indicate if a script overall has executed, too.  It does not "count" executions; that would make it a profiler (there are counting and timing profiler tools available from us for PHP, too).  See the website; there's a screenshow showing coverage on a set of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use __construct methode and log it if it is used. You can't set the __construct methode after creating an instance. So add them manually;

```
class Someclass{
private $clsName;
public function __construct(){
$this->clsName = get_class($this);
YourStaticLogger::yourlogFunction("whatever you want to log" . $this->clsName);
}
//other things
}
```

You can only track the called classes. That's what i would do.

Comment: This is the same answer as "add logging to each file".

Comment: nice but it won't work for abstract classes and parent classes that are extended by child classes since the child class will override the __construct methode of the parent class and there will only one __construct run for each instance.