# View unused (unlinked and unincluded) PHP files in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

I have a rather large Ecplise project with over 2000 php files and I suspect that there are a lot of them that is not in use.

I would like to generate a list over all php files that is not mentioned in any other file.
With mentioned I mean things like:

- `include('file.php')`
- `require_once('file.php')`
- `$linktoimportantpage = "file.php"`

So, pretty much all files that does not contain the string of any other filename in that project.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Brackets has a plugin with this feature. http://brackets.io/

Answer (score 3):

This script I wrote should do what you are looking for. It will search all PHP files in your project. Then it will search each file's contents for that file name, if the file name exists, obviously your don't want to delete it, so we can remove it from the array. You are then left with an array of files that are not "mentioned" in your project (the array will include the file path as well).

First let's set up the script:

```php
$path = realpath('/path/to/your/files');
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$php_files = array();
```

Next, loop through adding each file name to an array so we can search later:

```php
foreach ($objects as $name => $object)
{
    // only add php files to the array
    if($object->getExtension() !== 'php')
    {
                continue;           
    }

    $php_files[$name] = $object->getBasename();
}
```

Loop through again, but this time search each file:

```php
foreach ($objects as $name => $object)
{
    $path_parts = pathinfo($name);

    // again, only search php files to the array
    if($path_parts['extension'] == 'php')
    {
        // get the contents of each php file
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($name);

        // check each file name for an include
        foreach($php_files as $path => $filename)
        {
            // check if the file exist in this file contents
            if(strpos($file_contents, $filename) !== false)
            {
                // remove it from array if it exists in a file
                unset($php_files[$path]);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Print the array to see which files are left that are never included:

```php
print_r($php_files);
```

This will return an array in the following way:

```
Array
(
    [/path/to/file1.php] => file1.php
    [/path/to/file2.php] => file2.php
    [/path/to/file3.php] => file3.php
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this does not work as intended. If I use eclipse file search on workspace (ctrl+h) and search for footer.php I get 87 matches but footer.php is still showning in $php_files.

Comment: @daker I see. I updated the code and it should be working as your intend now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do that within Eclipse (the PHP plugin is simply not that powerful at the moment).

You can give a try to some source analyzer tools. Take a look [in this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392465/how-to-tell-which-php-files-are-actually-used-and-which-are-not) for example:

- [*How to tell which PHP files are actually used and which are not?* (Mar 2010; by NumberFour)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392465/how-to-tell-which-php-files-are-actually-used-and-which-are-not)

Answer (score 0):

I created a short script which will grep your project for unused php file imports.

**Usage:** `/path/to/file.sh application/directory` 
Make sure the script has permission to execute; eg:`chmod 777 /path/to/file.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

MYPATH=$1

find "$MYPATH" -name \*.php -exec basename {} \; > /tmp/patterns

for p in $(cat /tmp/patterns); do
    grep -R $p "$MYPATH" > /dev/null || echo $p;
done
```

Comment: Getting "find: paths must precede expression: aesctr.class.php"

Comment: Don't get any errors anymore but it seems to be VERY slow. Canceled it after ~30mins without any output.

Answer (score 0):

Just upfront: You have not written in your question about which PHP Eclipse plugin you're talking, so I assume you're talking about PDT.

To the best of my knowledge - and it is getting a bit rusty because I nowadays use PHPStorm - it is not possible with PDT to do include file de-referencing out of the box.

This is also generally true for anything that does static code-analysis because many things can not be resolved without the run-time context. For the examples you give:

- `include('file.php')` and `require_once('file.php')` contain references to files relative to the working directory *and* the include path. Both are unknown at the time of static code-analysis. Most tools can fetch the include path from project configuration, in PDT this is typically the build-path. The problem of the working directory is most often "solved" by just expecting the working directory to be the directory the file containing these include directives is in - but this must not be true at all.
- `$linktoimportantpage = "file.php"` would need to keep track of variable value evaluation. This can be possible in static code-analysis, but only very advanced tools will do it. I suspect that PDT does support this.

As the outlook seems pretty limited for static code-analysis to get a list of used files I personally would do a regular expression based search based on the pattern of the file-names. Here all files end on `.php`, often used in a string, so a regex to locate such places is:

```
\.php['"]
```

Eclipse PDT supports regular expressions within file-search from within the GUI. Nowadays - even I do use a different IDE mostly - I personally would do that on the commanline because it is more flexible. This can be done with the `find` and the `grep` command. They ship with their own help-pages and are easy to use. If you're using windows, you can install git-bash for windows which has a bash that contains all useful command-line tools for such things.

If you need a better impression, you can run your application and monitor all includes with an analyzer software called [inclued](http://pecl.php.net/package/inclued). It is a PECL package and it is documented in the PHP manual: http://php.net/inclued - it is pretty straight forward to use and does not have the shortcomings of the static code-analysis tools because it processes the runtime information.