# How can I check if specific file be used in php project and linux environment

Tags: php, linux

Currently I want to check if a specific file be used in php project

```
$target = "foobar.php";
$ beUsed = checkFile($target);
  
function checkFile($target){
    //code to check be here
    if (beUsed) return true;
    return false;
}
```

thanks for reading, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You want to search the file is used in the project?

Comment: Yes, I want to search file to be used in php project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392465/how-to-tell-which-php-files-are-actually-used-and-which-are-not

Check this.

Comment: I try but It is not the right answer to me. I want to check if a file to be used or required in another files in all project.

Comment: In `All` Project ?

Comment: Yes, all file in project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linux command

```
$target = "foobar.php";

searchFile($target);


function searchFile($target){
    $file_name = basename(__FILE__);

    $cmd = sprintf("grep -r --exclude='%s' %s ./* ",$file_name, $target);

    $res = exec($cmd);

    if($res){
        echo "Exists!" . PHP_EOL;

        print_r($res);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```